# Unable to send from external mail server (e.g. gmail) to postfix server

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I have set up a postfix server on a publicly accessible VM and configured it so that it's able to able to send emails to local accounts as well as other mail servers (e.g. gmail, yahoo e.t.c.) SPF and DMARC records for the domain have been set up just fine. The issue is when an email is sent from gmail, yahoo or other external mail servers to my mail server, it never gets there. The sending mail server does not display any error (e.g. Undelivered error e.t.c) and my receiving server does not seem to log this email as ever having been received. Any idea why I can send emails out to other mail servers but cannot receive emails from other mail servers?

```
sudo nmap -sS -O 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-09 10:50 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000014s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
5432/tcp open  postgresql
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 3.12 - 3.19, Linux 3.8 - 3.19
Network Distance: 0 hops
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = nectar.software
mydomain = nectar.software
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, nectar.software, ip-172-31-25-62.ec2.internal, localhost.ec2.internal, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
# SMTP-Auth settings
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
```

Comment: Have you setup MX records for your domain?  If your VM that is supposed to receive the email has no logs, then gmail likely hasn't contacted it.  Or, does your external VPS have a firewall in front of it?  What errors are you getting about your sent mail not getting there?

Comment: yap. I had set my MX records @Stephan. Turns out that the issue was by default, the created VMs come with the SMTP port blocked, which is of course good practice :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue, I had set my MX records and all other requirements for the mail server. The SMTP port was blocked by default in the AWS instance but this information is not only available from `netstat` but from looking at the inbound rules for the AWS instance's security group.